# SQL Trigger use inserted values to call stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to do the following but struggling to get the syntax correct to pass the inserted values to my stored procedure.

```
CREATE TRIGGER tInsertCall 
   ON cdr2
   FOR INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    EXEC Track.dbo.InsertCall inserted.calldate, inserted.clid, 
               inserted.src, inserted.dst, inserted.dcontext, inserted.channel, 
               inserted.dstchannel, inserted.lastapp, inserted.lastdata, 
               inserted.duration, inserted.billsec, inserted.disposition, 
               inserted.uniqueid, inserted.amaflags, inserted.recordingpath,
               inserted.accountcode, inserted.userfield
END
GO
```

Thanks

Comment: Inthe first place, never call a stored provc from a trigger.  What happens when multiple values are inserted in one statement? Thie trigger must handel set-based processes and NEVER UNDER ANY CIRCUMSTANCES run one record at a time.

Comment: It would be helpful to also post what error you get, I suspect you are attempting to use the inserted table (which is a table not a single row) as a single row.

Comment: The error is: incorrect syntax near '.'

Comment: The cdr2 table only ever has a single row inserted per statement.

Comment: You can't call a stored procedure using the columns from a table directly. If you are absolutely certain that you always insert only one row in that table per transaction, then you *could* first assign the columns of that row to different variables and then run the sp with those variables. Even so, you should still not create a trigger that can't handle more than 1 row per transaction

Answer (score 3):

You could create something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.tInsertCall ON dbo.cdr2
   FOR INSERT
AS 
BEGIN

    DECLARE @CallDate DATETIME;
    DECLARE @clid INT;
    .    --Add the other variables here
    .
    .
    DECLARE @userfield SOMEDATATYPE;

    SELECT TOP(1) @CallDate = INSERTED.calldate
        , @clid = INSERTED.clid
        ...    --Add the other variables here
        , @userfield = INSERTED.userfield
    FROM INSERTED;

    EXEC Track.dbo.InsertCall @CallDate, @clid, ... /*other variables here*/, @userfield;
END
GO
```

This trigger will only process the 1st row from the `INSERTED` virtual table, since it has `TOP(1)` in the `SELECT` statement.

The *better* (arguable) way to do this would be to use a trigger to iterate over all the rows in `INSERTED`.  Something like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.tInsertCall ON dbo.cdr2
   FOR INSERT
AS 
BEGIN

    DECLARE @CallDate DATETIME;
    DECLARE @clid INT;
    .   -- add the other variable declarations here
    .
    .
    DECLARE @userfield SOMEDATATYPE;

    -- use FAST_FORWARD and LOCAL to minimize locking etc
    DECLARE cur CURSOR FAST_FORWARD LOCAL FOR
    SELECT *
    FROM INSERTED;

    OPEN cur;

    --Get the first row from the INSERTED table
    FETCH NEXT FROM cur
    INTO @CallDate, @clid, ... /* other vars here */, @userfield;

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
    BEGIN
        -- run the stored proc
        EXEC Track.dbo.InsertCall @CallDate, @clid, .../* other vars here */, @userfield;
        -- get the next row from INSERTED
        FETCH NEXT FROM cur
        INTO @CallDate, @clid, .../* other vars here */, @userfield;
    END

    CLOSE cur;
    DEALLOCATE cur;

END
GO
```